# Python validation loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, validation, loops, text-files

I need to validate the user's name so it only contains letters. For this i am using a while true statement. I also want the username to be written to a text file once it is valid how would i change my code to do this. How would i change my code so if the user enters an invalid name they have to try again, and if it is valid it is written to a text file.

```
import re
name=(input("Please enter your name: "))
while name is None or not re.match("[A-z]",name):
  print("Invalid name. Try again")
  else:
    filename = ("name");
    with open (filename, "a") as f:
      f.write (name + "\n")
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Asking the user for input until they give a valid response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23294658/asking-the-user-for-input-until-they-give-a-valid-response)

Answer (score 1):

```
import re

def askName():
    name = input("Please enter your name: ")
    if re.match("[A-z]",name):
        with open("filename", "w") as f:
            f.write(name)
    else:
        askName()     

askName()
```

Answer (score 0):

From the [documention](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isalpha):

> **str.isalpha()**
>
> Return true if all characters in the string are alphabetic and there is at least one character, false otherwise. Alphabetic
>   characters are those characters defined in the Unicode character
>   database as “Letter”, i.e., those with general category property being
>   one of “Lm”, “Lt”, “Lu”, “Ll”, or “Lo”. Note that this is different
>   from the “Alphabetic” property defined in the Unicode Standard.

Something along the following lines should do the trick:

```
name = input('Enter name: ')

# if you want to take spaces into account, i.e. inputs like 
# 'Spam Eggs', change the following line to: 
# while any(x for x in name.split() if not x.isalpha()):

while not name.isalpha():
    print('Invalid input!')
    name = input('Enter name: ')

with open(filename, 'a') as f:
    f.write(name + '\n')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
name = raw_input('enter name\n')

while not all(map(lambda l: l.isalpha, iter(name)):
           name = raw_input('invalid name. Please try again\n')
           continue

with open('file_path', 'w') as f:
           f.write(name + '\n')
```

---

**all()** statement validates every char in the string; the **map** runs the **lambda** function for every char in the input. To create an iterator out of a string, you can use **iter(name)**

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps

```
Correct = True
while Correct == True:
    name = input("Please enter your name: ")
    if name.isalpha() == True:
        file = open("filename.txt", "a")
        file.write("\n" + name)
        file.close
        print("Wrote to file")
        Correct = False
    else:
        print("Incorrect, Try again")
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution upon many others:

```
while True:
    name=(input("Please enter your name: "))
    if name and name.isalpha():
        filename = ("name.txt")
        with open (filename, "a") as f:
            f.write (name + "\n")
        break
    else:
        print ("Invalid name. Try again")
        continue
```